# Can you metrize "convergence in probability with respect to every probability measure absolutely continuous"

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real valued (or more general) random variables and let $\mu$ be some Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ - not necessarily finite.

Suppose for every probability measure $P \ll \mu$ we have that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability wrt $P$. Is there a name for this convergence? Is it metrizable?

Comment: (i) "$X_n$ converges to $X$" ... In what sense? (ii) Can $\mu$ be assumed $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @IosifPinelis In probability wrt $P$. And sure

Comment: What is "sure"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis It means "yes, $\mu$ can be assumed to be $\sigma$-finite"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$According to this [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455871/can-you-metrize-convergence-in-probability-with-respect-to-every-probability-me#comment1180396_455871) by the OP, we may assume that the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. So, $\R$ can be partitioned into at most countably many Borel sets $B_1,B_2,\dots$ with $\mu(B_k)\in(0,\infty)$ for all $k$. Letting now
$$\nu(A):=\sum_k c_k\frac{\mu(A\cap B_k)}{\mu(B_k)}$$
for all Borel sets $A\subseteq\R$, where the $c_k$'s are positive real numbers such that $\sum_k c_k=1$, we see that $\nu$ is a probability measure equivalent to $\mu$: $\nu\ll\mu\ll\nu$.

So, if $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $P$ for every probability measure $P\ll\mu$, then $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $\nu$.

Vice versa, if $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $\nu$, then (say by dominated convergence) $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $P$ for every probability measure $P\ll\nu$ and hence wrt to $P$ for every probability measure $P\ll\mu$.

Thus, $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $P$ for every probability measure $P\ll\mu$ iff $X_n\to X$ in probability wrt to $\nu$.